# Why isn't my return statement being recognized?

Tags: java, return, return-type

It says it must return a string. But it already is. Then it says that it must have a return statement. But there is one there.

```
public String description() {
    String description = "";
    if (description != null)
        return description;
}
```

Comment: I need an else statement? I'm not sure how to fix it. I want it to do nothing, if it is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because if description is null then that return statement is never executed.
your code must be modfied to some thing like this

```
public String description() {
    String description = "";
    if (description != null){
        return description;
    }else{
     return null;
    }
}
```

I know that description is not equal to null but the compiler complains because if that if block is never executed then the method will not have a return statement, hence you need to have one outside it too.

Comment: a dead code means that you have written code after the return statement and that code will never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question the reason you get the error the you must have a return statement is that having the return statement within a conditional branch means that there is a possibility that it will not execute.  Since this method requires a return type you must include an else condition to return a value so all branches are covered.

Since Java performs a "pseudo compilation" it doesn't know that "description" is clearly not null until it runtime.

I just saw that you are wanting the method to do nothing in the event "description" is null.  In this case I would recommend throwing an exception:
    
    `@SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public String description() throws ValidationException {
            String description = "";
            if (description == null){
                throw new ValidationException("Some Error Message");
            }
            return description;
     }`

Comment: I changed it as suggested but am getting errors to either make it a block statement, delete it, or says it is dead code.

Comment: Please see my latest changes, this will help with the dead code message.